# Yosemite and HAXM 1.1.1 and "screen not available"

Tags: android, eclipse, haxm

I am running Yosemite and Eclipse.  I've installed HAXM 1.1.1.

I had the black screen issue with the emulator, so I turned on Enable GPU.

THe emulator runs, but I can't use the DDMS tools to do a screen capture.  It says "Screen not available.".

Anyone else have this issue?  Is it an Eclipse issue or HAXM or Yosemite issue?

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem. I checked to make sure HAXM was running command line[image: HAXM is Running] using the [instructions here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html).  No luck.  I'd love to hear an update on this thread.  I've searched around quite a bit.  My emulator hangs on a black screen, screenshot attached.[image: Intel_x86 Emulator Hanging on Black]

I also made sure my AVD was created using [the specs here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-kitkat-4-4-installation-instructions-recommended) from intel.